# php script called via ajax gives error on require_once

Tags: php, ajax, require-once

So I am not sure how to put this question but here it is.

I have a PHP script that I call via ajax.

The script has a require_once method call to include a needed php api library.

```
require_once 'lead-api.php';
```

This script worked fine until I added another require_once method call which is including another simple api library. But this time the library file is not located in the same folder so this is how I access it.

```
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/visitors/addVisitor.php';
```

but I get when I add this line and I cant tell what the error is, this is all I see.

[image]

The path for the file is correct, the file exists and works fine on other pages.

I have tried using full hard-coded path but it still gives the same error.

Not sure whats going wrong, any help will be appreciated.

Code removed

Comment: since you say that error comes only when you include the file `addVisitor.php`, then see the code in `addVisitor.php` and try to debug it or else put the code here

Comment: @Sourabh addVisitors.php works fine on other pages. Its been in production for over a year, and its a big file. I am now trying to figure out some way to output the php error somewhere. PHP Error logging is enabled but its not reporting any errors. I am going to try and debug the addVisitors.php. Maybe its conflicting with lead-api.php

Comment: 500 internal server error means your code for that file has an error, try to debug it or else post it here.

Comment: Are there any other includes in `addVisitor.php` which cannot be resolved from the path of your ajax file?

Comment: In continuation to @PlatinumIndustries comment, most chances your `...endFormData.php` file has errors. Consider sharing its code in order for us to help.

Comment: @BenjaminPaapYes addVisitor.php includes one file visitors-api.php

Comment: @Sourabh I have added the code addVisitor.php

Comment: If you fetch HTML contents from the file as a response make sure you have no trailing spaces after the file's php closing tag or have no php closing tag in the file. This causes gzip compression errors due to content being sent before the response was done ;)